# Error: No module named '__main__.forms'; '__main__' is not a package in Python3

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I am building a web app using Flask in Python. I have my main file named: flaskblog.py and it has following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

** # I have some code here****


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

above code worked fine and gave desired output, I have only one .py file as of here.

Now I have created a new .py file named: forms.py which has classes RegistrationForm and LoginForm and I tried to import these classes into flaskblog.py file, code is below,

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from .forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)

    ** # I have some code here****


if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run()
```

the above code is giving me error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.forms'; '**main**' is
>   not a package

I am new to promgramming and thinking some changes need to be done in `if __name__ == '__main__':` but not able to figure it out. can anyone assist please?

Comment: Use `from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm`. You're note in a package, so you can't use the relative dot-syntax for imports.

Comment: removing dot-syntax worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and welcome to SO. First I would recommend reading this link: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/ since it explains how Python modules and packages are working.

You should be able to solve the from if you change:

`from .forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm`

to:

`from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm`